# Selecting columns from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a string with my needed columns, which i want to select. For example:

```
@sqlstring = 'col1,col2,col3'
```

I want select columns from table using this string. Like

```
SELECT @sqlstring FROM MyTable
```

But choose only this string, as much as columns count in table

```
col1,col2,col3 
col1,col2,col3 
col1,col2,col3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)=  'SELECT '+  @sqlstring + ' FROM MyTable '
EXEC (@SQL)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=212742bd4805fe5a26df820899194d78)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL.  When doing so in SQL Server, I recommend using `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @sql varchar(max);

set @sql = '
select @sqlstring
from my_table
';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@sqlstring', @sqlstring);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016 they have introduced Split string function: `STRING_SPLIT`

```
DECLARE @sqlstring  varchar(100) = 'col1,col2,col3'
DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR = ','    
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Value' 
FROM  
(     
     SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@sqlstring, @Delimiter, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data            
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```